# Bug zapper project with counter

Tags: arduino, voltage, multiplier

I have this evil thought that building a fly zapper with a counter every time it works.

There are two ways in my mind, first one is hacking a bug zapper product which I already have (hand grip style, will use 9v adapter instead its battery). But my question is, how do I put a counter on its high voltage end. Is there any way to limit a proportional voltage at the output for safe arduino reading?

Other way is the capacitor voltage multiplier path, which is easy to read for me but I don't know which would be easiest to make.

Comment: When it zap a bug, it will create a distinctive sound, can you count that ?

Comment: Wonderful idea on dsp part, very creative! Yet it would be overkill imho :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sensing the voltage on the output cap should not be too difficult.

My guess is that there already is a bleeding resistor in parallel with the output capacitor. For a crude circuit, you can add a few diodes on the bottom side, so that you see a high to low transition when a bug is zapped.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkHwYC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This works only if the cap is fully discharged when a bug is zapped, which is unlikely. Worth a try if you have some diodes around, and a fair amount of bugs too.

You can give another shot to capacitive coupling:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsmncE.png)</sup>

Note that C2 here should be able to withstand all the output voltage.

In DC the voltage to the micro is the Vdd, through R2. When a bug is zapped, the voltage of C1 drops (a lot), so does the voltage to the micro. D2 protects the micro from negative spikes, you might be fine with the protections inside the micro itself.

D1 is probably not necessary, as the voltage rises quite slowly on C1 so basically you charge C2 and do not see positive spikes. I would simulate that, just in case. If you really need to dump a lot of charge on Vdd, you might need a resistive path to ground, some 10 mA or so. Also lowering C2 should help.

Comment: In the second picture above, wouldn't dioedes fry on high voltages, say about 2k volts? Your post inspired me about diodes, how about I use like 7 diodes cascaded to negative side, 7x0,7=4,9 volts and just measure that?

Comment: The diodes would not fry, it is more about the total energy they must dissipate rather than voltage. The first circuit only works if the cap is (almost) fully discharged, you can make some tests but I do not expect it to go down to 0 V each time.